# Is it UITableView or colorWithPatternImage problem? Background image turns white although it is light gray color

Tags: iphone

I am using the following way to set the background of the UITableView.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
```

The image which I want to set as the background is light gray color But the image which I see is totally white.

What is the problem. Like is it with the colorWithPatterImage or with the UITable.

Comment: Accessing parentViewController.view is a terrible idea - you don't know what kind of backing it has, and it's a pretty bad violation of encapsulation.  Even if it works now, the next iOS update may totally break your code. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

This link was helpful...

[UITableView background image alpha problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477325/uitableview-background-image-alpha-problems)

setting the opaque property to NO solved the problem but I want to know why was this problem occurred.

Answer (score -1):

If you kust want to set some custom color as a background, you can use

> ```
> [UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha]
> ```